# Use for loop for array provide errror

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I use the following code that works as expected, while using a ESLINT
i got error

> ESLint: iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too
> heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be
> avoided in favor of array iterations. (no-restricted-syntax)

**This is the code**

```
for (const subscription of resp.data.subscriptions) {
  if (subscription.url) {
    return subscription.url;
  }
}
```

The code is simply

- get an array of data from other function
- loop on each array item
- when the first array instance have url take it and return

Is there a way to write it better to avoid the eslint issue ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a debate about `for...of` usage [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1271) and its eventual restriction

> `for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) { ... }` is antiquated syntax,
> and while I know everyone understands what it means, we should be
> leaving it behind.
>
> `array.map` has functional connotations and we shouldn't be producing
> side effects in the closure.
>
> `array.forEach` is an option, but I personally don't like it for this
> sort of imperative work.
>
> So I think the ForOfStatement should be removed from the restricted
> syntax for the above reasons - anyone with any conflicting viewpoints?
> Do we know what the original justification is?

`for..of` is more expensive than `forEach`, check [this](https://www.incredible-web.com/blog/performance-of-for-loops-with-javascript/) out

I have no opinions, you could just remove the eslint rule

Comment: I am particularly against bulls**t like `"for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) { ... } is antiquated syntax, and while I know everyone understands what it means, we should be leaving it behind."` Everyone understands it. It is BY FAR the most performant code in the bunch, but we should "leave it behind". We don't have a compiler to mitigate the effects of iterators on performance, so throwing away your most performing solution is simply dumb.

Comment: I agree, developers affects sugar syntax way too much sometimes and want to be cool by using latest. But `forEach` could improve readability so, as I said, I have no opinions

Comment: `forEach` isn't always a workable substitute, though, since `break` isn't valid in a forEach loop. If you need to bail when something has happened once (e.g., in the code I'm doing now, when the first shape has a true hit test, I don't want to look at any more), then we're back to the same choices again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to solve this:

```
var arrObjWithURL = resp.data.subscriptions.filter(function(item) {
    return item.url;
});

if (arrObjWithURL.length > 0) {
    return arrObjWithURL[0];
}
```

You can also use [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
return resp.data.subscriptions.find(function(item) {
    return item.url;
});
```

... or this to continue if there is no URL found:

```
const objWithUrl = resp.data.subscriptions.find(function(item) {
    return item.url;
});

if (objWithUrl !== undefined) {
    return objWithUrl;
}
```

[**demo on jsfiddle.net**](https://jsfiddle.net/vfLac41o/)

Comment: Maybe [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is a better option for this problem

Comment: Thanks, assume I've another code after the `find` function it's not reacble, how can overcome this? I mean if `find` find url return, otherwise proceed to the next code in the function ....

Comment: @BenoOdr updated answer. You can check the return value of find for `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, one last question, I want to learn :) the `find` code is better on this case then the `for` in nodejs ? I mean looping on array, which have better performance ? im not an expert...